# Fluent NHibernate Order by Property in related Entity

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, sql-order-by

I have 2 tables in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE [items](
    [item_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [item_name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [group_id] [int] NOT NULL   
)

CREATE TABLE [itemgroup](
    [group_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [group_name] [varchar](50) NULL 
)
```

and here are mapping classes for these entities:

```
    public class ItemMap : ClassMap<Item>
    {
        public ItemMap()
        {
            Table("items");
            Id(x => x.Id).Column("item_id");
            Map(x => x.Name).Column("item_name");
            References(x => x.ItemGroup).Column("group_id").Fetch.Join();            
        }
    }
    public class ItemGroupMap : ClassMap<ItemGroup>
    {
        public ItemGroupMap()
        {
            Table("itemgroup");
            Id(x => x.Id).Column("group_id");
            Map(x => x.Name).Column("group_name");
        }
    }
```

**How can I get all items from the database ordered by group name?**
Just in case I'm using Fluent NHibernate v1.2.0.712.

Comment: What method of querying are you using Criteria, QueryOver, Linq, or HQL?

Comment: @Vadim I use Criteria for getting all items, here is an example of my code: 
`using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
 {                
   return session.CreateCriteria(typeof(TEntity)).AddOrder(CreateOrder(sortedBy, sortDirection)).SetFirstResult((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).SetMaxResults(pageSize).List<TEntity>();
}`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add 
`private static Order CreateOrder(string sortedBy, string sortDirection)
{
   return new Order(sortedBy, true);
}`
sortedBy is the property name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add a join to your criteria.

```
var criteria = Session.CreateCriteria<Item>()
                      .CreateAlias("ItemGroup", "group")
                      .AddOrder(Order.Asc("group.Name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

in your ItemGroup you must have a list of Item, suppose you call it Items

Then in ItemGroupMap add

```
mapping.HasMany(x => x.Items)
            .Cascade.All()
            .Inverse()
            .SetAttribute("order-by", "item_name");
```

Now you can have a list of ItemGroup with all children ordered by item_name

Comment: This will get all items for a group ordered by name. OP wants all items from the db ordered by item group name.