# Fluent NHibernate join tables in mapping not using primary key

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to create one entity from 2 tables that are related not by primary key

**Tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE [employees](
    [ssn] [nvarchar](9) NULL,
    [active] [bit] NULL,    
    [employee_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL 
)


CREATE TABLE [sam_employees](
    [ssn] [nvarchar](9) NULL,
    [first_name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [last_name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [skill] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    ....
)
```

**SQL to generate:**

```
SELECT this_.employee_id  as employee1_0_0_,
       this_.ssn          as ssn0_0_,
       this_.active       as active0_0_,
       this_1_.first_name as first2_1_0_,
       this_1_.last_name  as last3_1_0_,
       this_1_.skill      as skill1_0_
FROM   employees this_
       inner join sam_employees this_1_
         on this_.ssn = this_1_.ssn
WHERE  this_.active = 1
```

**My current mapping:**

```
public class EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        Table("employees");
        Id(x => x.Id, "employee_id");
        Map(x => x.SSN, "ssn");
        Map(x => x.IsActive, "active");

        Join("sam_employees", mm =>
                                  {                                          
                                      mm.KeyColumn("ssn");
                                      mm.Map(xx => xx.FirstName, "first_name");
                                      mm.Map(xx => xx.LastName, "last_name");
                                      mm.Map(xx => xx.Skill, "skill");
                                  });            
    }
}
```

But with this mapping I have such join condition on this_.employee_id = this_1_.ssn

I know that this question was asked before but I didn't find a good answer for it, just workaround to use View in database side instead of tables.

Comment: So what exactly is your problem?  It's joining on ssn but you don't want it to?

Comment: @Cole W I want to join by ssn on both sides, but I have employee_id from one side and ssn from another.

Comment: I see what you're saying now.  I agree with Vadim below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try mapping sam_employees as an entity and use a References mapping with a join type fetch.

Comment: Agree I can do it, but I think it's another workaround for this problem.

Comment: I don't think you'll find a 'real' solution then, short of submitting a patch to NHibernate as you cannot specify a property to use in join mapping.

Comment: Could you help me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833259/fluent-nhibernate-order-by-property-in-related-entity by using QueryOver. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of help are you looking for? You already accepted my answer on that question.