# Mapping multiple tables into a single object with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a schema that looks like this:

[image]

There is a one to one relationship between Foo and Bar and a many to one relationship between Bar and Baz.

I have Foo and Baz mapped to separate objects, but I'm not sure how to go about linking them using Bar, without making Bar a separate object. (I want to be able to access Baz as a property of Foo)

It looks like it should be possible as it's very similar to the example given [here](http://ayende.com/blog/3961/nhibernate-mapping-join), except using a many-to-one relationship instead of a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you will be able to accomplish what you want using a join.  You'll end up with problems trying to join Foo and Bar.  See these 2 articles:

[Fluent NHibernate join tables in mapping not using primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835633/fluent-nhibernate-join-tables-in-mapping-not-using-primary-key)
[Fluent NHibernate join for property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031630/fluent-nhibernate-join-for-property-value)

I'm not sure there is a great way around this without making bar an entity.

Comment: Thanks for the links, it looks like I'll probably just have to map a Bar object.